# Can move unallocated space to my linux partition , urgent

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, ubuntu-one, unallocated

[image]

That's the condition of my disks seen from live ubuntu cd.

On /dev/sd8 my ubuntu os is Installed

On /dev/sd1 windows 7 is Installed.

And i want to merge the unallocated space on top of /dev/sd7 to my ubuntu partition because I'm running out of space.

I tried solutions mentioned in internet but i couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Then all my installed programs will be removed!

Comment: I would suggest booting a live (Ubuntu install media) deleting **sda7** or your swap partition, then add space wanted to **sda8** (resize), then re-create a swap partition (and fix any issues such as move causing MBR to point to wrong location and grub issues [if this occurs], a change in UUID for swap in /etc/fstab etc.) –

Comment: Sorry - I deleted my comment which listed the wrong sda number; my text was correct (ie.  **delete the later recreate swap partition** to allow the partition to expand)  You could `move` swap too, but it may still mean fixing grub due to partition expansion (if /boot is moved on disk)..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should strait forward: Delete the swap partition on /dev/sda7 and then resize the ext4 on /dev/sda8.

There is one important step before that: The live CD auto mounts the swap space, so you need to disable swap before you can remove the partition:

```
$ sudo swapoff
```

An then you can remove the swap space. If you have enough memory, you don't need it anyway. With only 2GB you will need a swap partition. So after deleting the swap partition and resizing/moving /dev/sda8, boot Windows and shrink /dev/sda5. Than you can create a new swap partition. Ubuntu doesn't care were it is.

Also shrinking the /dev/sda5 partition might be a good idear anyway, since it would solve all your problems.

Comment: If i delete swap partition, what problems it will cause?

Comment: My computer is 32bit with 2GB ram

Comment: None as long as you don't start Firefox or LibreOffice.

Comment: 2GB is not much... so you might need a swap partition. You have a nother partition on /dev/sda9. If that wone is free, you can use it as swap.

Comment: Thank You Guys, it worked. I deleted the swap and merged the unallocated space to my linux partition and created another linux swap. But after reboot as usual i got a grub rescue prompt but this article helped me to fix that problem https://medium.com/@froositadwi/how-i-fixed-error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found-b44c5ac7ff31

Comment: @simon-sudler  I've a question, though I've created a swap , i checked that it's not mounting automatically on boot as it was doing before, how can i solve that?

Comment: add `/dev/sdaX none swap defaults 0 0` to `/etc/fstab` (with X is the number of your new swap partition